# TrackPoint and its keys stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, trackpoint

Touchpad as well as TrackPoint and its key on my Lenovo ThinkPad T480s were working just fine until they started acting weird (unresponsive, pointer going all over the screen, etc.), then they all stopped working.

I managed to find a solution for the touchpad. But the TrackPoint is dead. I couldn't find any solution. Can anybody help?

Since I managed to make the touchpad work again, I believe I am facing a software problem here and not hardware.

I tried disabling `psmouse` and enabling it again. It didn't work.

Below is the output of `xinput` if it may help.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```